# How in ant use "<" in text?

Tags: ant

I want use this code:

```
replaceregexp match='app_name">(.*)<'
```

But char **<** can't be used.
How can I do it?

Comment: I had never heard of Ant before, yet I found what seems to be the answer in 1 minute. Perhaps you forgot research this yourself before posting.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use characters which stand for predefined standard entities in attribute value or text, you must write it as entity.

Predefined entity covers " ' < > &

In your case you have to write

```
replaceregexp match='app_name&quot;&gt;(.*)&lt;'
```

(The single quot limits the attribute value here, when a single quote appear IN the value you have to use the entity ')

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for the characters `<>`.

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=721755